# MySQL 8.0: Error on trying to install keyring

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

Using MySQL 8.0 and MySQL Workbench on Windows 10. Also using Command Prompt to interface with mysql after cd'ing into C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin.

I'm trying to implement encryption data-at-rest on several tables on a database. However, after trying to install keyring_file.dll via

```
install plugin keyring_file soname 'keyring_file.dll';
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'keyring_file'; Plugin initialization function failed.
```

I have added the following to my.cnf under mysqld:

```
[mysqld]
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.dll
keyring_file_data=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/plugin/keyring_file
```

After restarting MySQL server via services.msc, I ran 'show variables like '%keyring%';' which returned the following:

[image]

Running the following:

```
SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';
```

Also returned:

[image]

Not sure what I have done wrong or missed out. Looking at similar questions and solutions for this issue don't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: Are you running the paid for version of MySQL? If not that feature does not work, surprisingly

Comment: No, I'm using the Free version. I don't really want to spend thousands on a subscription either...

Comment: Then like I said, ___encryption at rest___ only works if you ___shell out the thousands on a subscription___. They godda make a buck somewhere otherwise there would be no development

Comment: Ah ok, cheers for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem, following steps resolve my issue

1. check error log and found the permission issue cause the problem.
2. create a folder "Plugin" on "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0" (data directory path).
3. copy keyring_file.dll from "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin" to "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Plugin".
4. set keyring_file_data=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Plugin\keyring in my.ini file.
5. restart the mysql service
6. execute mysql> install plugin keyring_file soname 'keyring_file.dll';